# How to use the regular code snippets in the 2018 Stack Overflow update

Tags: support, stack-snippets, code-formatting, code, ask-question-wizard-2018

I am a little confused with the new update of Stack Overflow, particularly on using the regular JavaScript/CSS/HTML code snippets we used to have to write our questions. Now the new update made it unclear, at least to me.

I can't find a way to open the code snippet and all I find is that I should manually indent four spaces each line, plus what I write is plain text, not code, and it only turns to code when I post the question, which obviously made it harder to write code in questions.

I am sure I am missing something as updates are meant to make our lives easier not the opposite.

P.S, code snippets are still here in the Meta Stack Overflow, but not on the Stack Overflow itself any more.

Comment: Is this related to the ask question wizard? You always had to provide 4 spaces while adding code block.. Plus there is a preview section to see your content as code

Comment: "..what I write is plain text not code and it only turns to code when I post the question": no. What you write is [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Pretty sure this is about the wizard. Aren’t stack snippets supported on the wizard?

Comment: when I am using the old code snippets, which I was able to open by `Ctrl-M` or clicking on a little code icon, I didn't have to manually indent 4 spaces, I simply write whichever code I want, so `.js` code for example, the `const` keyword turns into blue like in the text editor, and so on.. this is no longer available in the new update. so my question is how to use it again.. sorry guys I am actually only about 4 months-old in Stack overflow, your help is highly appreciated

Comment: @yivi, I think yes this has to do with this wizard thing, and no the snippets aren't supported there, or at least I can't seem to find it.

Comment: ooh alright, I did find it, so i just had to click on preview to have the option to write in the snippet as I used to, problem solved, thanks again to yall

Comment: I think this is relevant to be documented, would you mind to write a self-answer to this question?

Comment: sure, I am doing that now, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @MoSwilam The Ask Question Wizard is currently in AB beta testing. Your feedback is certainly appreciated by Stack Overflow; it's little oversights like these that they seek to remedy before releasing the Wizard to everyone.

Answer (score 13):

I found how to open the snippet with the helping comments of @suraj and @yivi.

In the new question wizard I am asked to explain my question and write the code in plain text. It is not clearly mentioned that I should click on **Review** to be able to see and open the code snippet to write my code.

So, I just needed to go to Review, which is right above where I am writing the question, to open it. That's it, thanks again. :)