# Stack Overflow Chrome Question only Guided Mode

Tags: support, google-chrome, ask-question-wizard-2018

It's really annoying for me that in Chrome on Stack Overflow I just can use the Guided Mode to ask a question. In Firefox I get an normal editor.
Chrome is so annoying because the whole editor is missing like to mark something and click on {} to make sure it is formatted to code. And even Ctrl + K does not work for me in Chrome.

Why do I have this only in Chrome?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot? Is that on the last page of the wizard or somewhere in the middle? This earlier question seems related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378373/578411

Comment: Of course here: https://imgur.com/a/xedmArB thats the editor I only get

Comment: Right. Once you are on the review tab, you'll find the full blown editor again. Given the load of questions that are subpar we rather have new users focus on content first before they are bothered about formatting. But the confusion is understandable if have seen both the old-style and this guided approach to asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The editor you're seeing in Chrome is part of a [temporary experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378057/1709587) being run by the staff to find out how the wizard will affect the behaviour of new users asking questions. Some new users get shown it, and others don't. Given what you're seeing, I guess that whether that happens gets determined and stored in your browser, rather than being fixed per user account.

I agree it's a pretty crappy editing experience. Fortunately, as rene points out in the comments, there's a workaround: just write some random filler content in the guided mode boxes, then click "Next Step" to get the full editor and remove whatever you wrote, then write your post the normal way.

Comment: Oh gosh yes now i realised that there is the right window to edit and even Ctrl + K works here with Chrome... this guided mode is horrible :D not even Ctrl + K worked and gets on my nerves

Comment: I much agree with the first paragraph. I disapprove of the word "crap" in the last paragraph as it offers bad advice. Whatever the implementation of the wizard, users should never put in random crap.

Comment: @rene If the user's objective is just to get through to the real editor so they can actually write a proper question, putting in random crap seems like as good an approach as any, to me.

Comment: @rene My deviant use of bad words has now been corrected by The Man, although since I think your objection was to the substance of what I was proposing rather than the use of bad words, it probably doesn't do anything mitigate your disapproval.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure where I point out the workaround @samuelliew but if that works better for everyone I'm happy to take the blame. It is not that important.