# "Ask a question process" different on Chrome to IE

Tags: support, internet-explorer, ask-question-wizard-2018

When I ask a question using IE (11.472.17134.0) I am taken through to a page with 5 headers "Type, Tags, Title, Description, Review" and asked to fill in these sections as I go.

Each section has it hints and tips on what to fill in. It's almost like it treating me a a new user and taking me through a Stack Overflow tutorial.

When I use the same login and go through Chrome (71.0.3578.98) it presents with the standard one page "Ask a Question" section with Title, Body and Tags.

Anyone else had this issue?

Comment: For more info, see the featured post about the new ask question wizard: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378057/the-ask-question-wizard-is-now-in-testing

Comment: Apparently SO believes that if you are posting from IE you are more likely to need your hand held. Not an entirely crazy proposition.

Comment: Very related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378764/stackoverflow-chrome-question-only-guided-mode

Comment: A better question is: why are you using IE? ;)

Comment: Company policy... sigh. Luckily Chrome is installed on our development machines for website testing.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a typical A/B testing pattern.

Stack Overflow doesn't discuss their testing methodology or what browsers they look at, but the big thing here is that you're part of the new [Ask Question Wizard testing group](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378057/the-ask-question-wizard-is-now-in-testing) on at least one browser.

Give it a try and see how it works for you.  If you don't like it, leave *that* feedback here in a different Meta question and state what you didn't like.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations! For some reason, SO is taking you through the [Ask Question Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378057/3551604) on IE. It's strange that being in the test or not isn't (apparently) a per-account thing, though. (Perhaps that's how it's supposed to be? Must do more research...)